# Symfony 5.2 Error: The directory "var/cache/dev/jms_serializer" does not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony5, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Symfony 5.2 with jms/serializer-bundle 3.7.0.

After symfony cache cleaning by command  `cache:clear` on the next request I get an error:

> The directory "var/cache/dev/jms_serializer" does not exist

I noticed that for symfony 4.4 [$dir variable](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/0ee8b75bfc484a342aa0471e3c6d9ad96fb430cf/DependencyInjection/JMSSerializerExtension.php#L99) has `var/cache/de_/jms_serializer` value, but for symfony 5.2 has `var/cache/dev/jms_serializer`

So when symfony 5.2 runs warn up, JMSSerializerBundle creates `jms_serializer` folder in `var/cache/dev` instead of `var/cache/de_`

serializer config:

```
jms_serializer:
    visitors:
        xml_serialization:
        format_output: '%kernel.debug%'
    property_naming:
        id: 'jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in symfony 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Try to just remove cache directory.

```
rm -rf var/cache
```

And create it with php user:

```
sudo su www-data // Login as php user
mkdir var/cache // create cache directory
chown -R $USER:$USER var/cache // Change owner of cache directory
```

where instead of www-data is the user which run your php.

**P.S.** I am not fully sure, but there is no `var/de` directory neither for symfony, neither for serializer. It is just an temporary directory created by symfony while clearing cache process, which is usually removed after successful finish

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use `cache:clear` command. 
If I'm not mistaken `var/de_` directory is used for warn-up cache and this directory will be renamed to `var/dev` when original  `var/dev` directory are deleted.

Comment: I believe that old `de_` directory is messed up and does not let override cache with new one. You need to delete it somehow.

Comment: `var/de_` directory  isn't removed, it's renamed to `var/dev`  after successful finish, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/8b51547061b29081803eb9fdf9b02cf80a1e1a74/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php#L177

Comment: symfony  fixed that in 5.2.1 version